# How to override browser font?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am newbie to CSS.
Specifically, now I am using IE8. My web page works fine with `MS PGothic` font in `japanese script`. But when we change IE8 browser font to `Arial Unicode MS`. The webpage does not look fine. This happens only in IE8, in firefox and chrome, even change is OK.

My problem is 
I have so many CSS files more than 200.

- So I want to change my browser font to MS PGothic  for my website
- or use only web page font not use browser font?

Which is possible? I want to know code sample for that. Any help is are greatly appreciated.

Before changing to Arial Unicode MS
[image: Before changing]

After changing to Arial Unicode MS
[image: After changing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to specify the font in your CSS, which can be done this way (falling back to a sans-serif font):

```
body {
  font-family: "MS PGothic", sans-serif;
}
```

If you have so many CSS files, however, the `font-family` value be overridden in one of them, so you might want to use the `!important` value, like this:

```
body {
  font-family: "MS PGothic", sans-serif !important;
}
```

This can be improved further by including selectors for `input` and `textarea` so that form fields use this font as well:

```
body, input, textarea {
  font-family: "MS PGothic", sans-serif !important;
}
```

We can also use the Japanese font name as well, just in case. Finally, I recommend specifying the Meiryo font which looks smoother than MS PGothic and is available on Windows Vista and above. Also, fonts for Mac should be included so I think the best CSS for Japanese pages is something like this:

```
body, input, textarea {
  font-family: "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", Osaka, "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Now I am Ok with it.